# Facing issue while upgrading from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.x

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

[image]

I have an already existing SpringBoot 1.x application which is using Java 7.I want to upgrade spring boot version from 1.x to 2.x.
For up gradation I have upgraded java version from 1.7 to 1.8 in maven pom.xml.
In existing application I am using apache log4j(org.apache.log4j.*) for logging purpose.Getting compilation error for log4j after up gradation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to add more detail. What error are you getting, for example.

Comment: @ptomli I am getting comilation error. Log4j class is not coming in classpath.

Comment: Don't add a comment, copy the output of your compilation into the question. That way people can see the actual error, not your (perhaps incorrect) interpretation.

Comment: I have updated the description.Please find above.

Comment: Make sure log4j is in your pom.xml

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Boot 1.4, the log4j (1.x) starter module is no longer available:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#deprecations-from-spring-boot-13

You can either switch to log4j2 (which still has a starter module) or you'll have to manually provide the log4j dependencies 1.x in your POM.